# error: excess elements in array initializer

Tags: initializer

error: excess elements in array initializer

> #include "Connector.h"
> #include <stdint.h>
>
> #include "../blackrussia/Java.h"
>
> const char* g_szServerNames[MAX_SERVERS] = {
> "BLACK RUSSIA | RED",
> "BLACK RUSSIA | TEST"
> };
>
> const CSetServer::CServerInstanceEncrypted g_sEncryptedAddresses[MAX_SERVERS] = {
> CSetServer::create("185.189.15.22", 1, 16, 6515, true), // указывать тут
> CSetServer::create("185.189.15.22", 1, 16, 6515, true), // и тут тоже что сверху
> CSetServer::create("185.189.15.22", 2, 16, 1531, true), // указывать тут
> CSetServer::create("185.189.15.22", 2, 16, 1531, true) // и тут тоже что сверху
> };

I tried a lot of things, it didn't help

Comment: How's `MAX_SERVERS` defined?